# Cassandra getting data (query on different attributes)

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datamodel

how i can get data from Cassandra using value

```
posts = {

    '1': {   //this post id 
        'user_id': '4',
        'body': 'This is awesome!',
    },

}
```

i cen get the post using post id 
can i get posts related to certain user

i mean get post related to user_id=4 like an example (query using user_id attribute)

regrads

Answer (score 3):

For that you will need to maintain your own (secondary) index.
e.g

```
userIds = {

    '4': {   //this user id
        'post_id': '1'
    },

}
```

Comment: you mean that i need to create antoher column family contain (usersid-postid)